# PATA to SATA convertor for FW400 enclosure?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata, firewire, pata

I have a decent USB2/FW400 HD enclosure with an old 250GB PATA HD inside. I am using its FW400 interface. I would like to reuse the box with a newer SATA drive but I wonder if the SATA-PATA adapter ruins the performance.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 controllers in series will cause problems, the controller in the enclosure and the pata to sata controller. Those sata controllers that plug into the back of the Pata drive rarely work well, Its time to upgrade the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

I have used these adapters with success but only as a connection to the motherboard controller.  They work fine but performance will only be as fast as teh slowest component.  The bigger issue would be fitting the adapter into the enclosure.  Any I have used were large enough that they would not fit into the case